# How to get Clean Terminal in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, path

I want to have a clean Terminal in VSC, but every time I run my code there is some useless stuff I would like to remove, for example my Microsoft Version and the path to my files.

Is there any way to remove them from my Terminal?

On all my other PC's I don't have this Problem, only on this PC. I already tried to  change the console argument in my Launch.json but if I change it to InternalConsole it dosen't run the code anymore. Also it would show my results in the debugger and I would like to use the Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear your Terminal after each run, by typing `clear` in Terminal. To have it done automatically, check 'Clear Before Reusing', or 'Clear Previous Output' (if you're using Code Runner) in Settings. To get there, press `Ctrl + ,` on Win or `Command + ,` on Mac and type 'clear' in the search box.

[image]

Sending the output to the Debug console looks cleaner, but it doesn't allow user input. Other than that, I don't think there's a way to not have the path of your file displayed as the file executes.